# Python3 how to add <br> tag to each element in array after 4 words?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I have an array **ElementA**

```
ElementA=["Hello my name is Karen", "Andrew here with you and nice to meet you", "Hi, Sharon here"]
```

I wish to gerate an output for the array which will return as below:

```
OutputElementA= ["Hello my name is <br> Karen", "Andrew here with you <br> and nice to meet <br> you", "Hi, Sharon here"]
```

Anyone have ideas on this how to add a 
 tag to an element in array after 4 words of each element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it.

```
ElementA=["Hello my name is Karen", "Andrew here with you and nice to meet you", "Hi, Sharon here"]
OutputElementA = []

for elem in ElementA:
    #Split string into words
    elem_list = elem.split(' ')
    out_elem_str = ''
    i=0
    elem_item = []
    while i < len(elem_list):
        elem_item = elem_list[i:i+4]
        if len(elem_item) == 4:
            out_str = ' '.join(elem_item)+' <br> '
            out_elem_str += out_str
        i+=4
    out_elem_str += ' '.join(elem_item)
    OutputElementA.append(out_elem_str)

print(OutputElementA)
```

The output is

```
['Hello my name is <br> Karen', 
'Andrew here with you <br> and nice to meet <br> you', 
'Hi, Sharon here']
```